# Why does the kubernetes run the coreDNS as deployment in the cluster, rather than a static pod?

Tags: kubernetes, dns

[image]

The Kubernetes controlplane usually run components as static pods:

- kube-apiserver: static pod
- kube-scheduler: static pod
- kube-controller-manager: static pod
- etcd: static pod

The DNS is also the essential component of whole cluster, but why do authors of kubernetes run CoreDNS as a `Deployment + Service`, rather than static pod?

Could you please explain the key factors and considerations of this design?